# Select joining X to Y is ten times faster than joining Y to X -- why is this?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

I don't know much about MySQL, just what any non-DBA programmer knows: how to get the data in and out.

I had a page on my site which was running very slowly and the query was the bottleneck. It was taking ten seconds to do this:

```
    SELECT foo, bar, baz, bax
    FROM small_table
    LEFT JOIN
    large_table
    on small_table.id = large_table.thread_id
```

I didn't have any indexes, so I indexed the id columns. Now it was taking six seconds.

Then I did a bit of reading, tried the `ANALYZE` and `EXPLAIN` commands but didn't really understand them, and then just for the experiment, changed the tables around:

```
    SELECT foo, bar, baz, bax
    FROM large_table <-- first
    LEFT JOIN
    small_table <-- second
    on small_table.id = large_table.thread_id
```

and now it took *zero-point-six* seconds.

[The app is a forum. small_`table` lists the threads (100 records), and large_`table` contains posts made on those threads (20,000 records).]

I can, of course, continue to experiment, but some questions:

- What principle have I uncovered?
- What's the best way to proceed, in general, when I have a slow select?
- In the above example, do I even have the same `SELECT` as I did before? It produces exactly the same results.
- What was I supposed to learn from `ANALYZE` and `EXPLAIN`?

Answer (score 3):

I bet the resulting data are different... Except if the columns you're keeping in the select all are in the small table.

`left join` keeps every row from the first table and add the rows from the second table when a match exists.

In your first case, the first table is the large on, so you have a lot of rows.

In your second case, the first table is the small on, so you have way less rows, thus the query is faster.

Comment: Could you please be explicit about what's the "first" table? The first in document order? Because I'm saying the query runs faster with big_table JOIN small_table, and you seem to be suggesting it should be the other way around.   [BTW, I think the data will be the same for reasons to do with other parts of the query I left out.]